# Screeps access 'main' variable from another file?

Tags: javascript

in the game screeps i try to call an variable from another file.
Thats my main file:

```
var roleHarvester = require('role.harvester');
var roleUpgrader = require('role.upgrader');
var roleBuilder = require('role.builder');
var roleVoyager = require('role.voyager');
var roleAttacker = require('role.attacker');
var roleTransporter = require('role.transporter');
var roleHealer = require('role.healer');
var roleRepairer = require('role.repairer');

module.exports.loop = function () {

    for(var name in Memory.creeps) {
        if(!Game.creeps[name]) {
            delete Memory.creeps[name];
            console.log('Clearing non-existing creep memory:', name);
        }
    }

    var harvesters = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'harvester');
    console.log('Harvesters: ' + harvesters.length);

    var upgraders = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'upgrader');
    console.log('Upgraders: ' + upgraders.length);

    var builders = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'builder');
    console.log('Builders: ' + builders.length);

    var voyagers = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'voyager');
    console.log('Voyagers: ' + voyagers.length);

    var attackers = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'attacker');
    console.log('Attackers: ' + attackers.length);

    var transporters = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'transporter');
    console.log('Transporters: ' + transporters.length);

    var healers = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'healer');
    console.log('Healers: ' + healers.length);

    var repairers = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'repairer');
    console.log('Repairers: ' + repairers.length);


    if(harvesters.length < 3) {
        var newName = Game.spawns['SpawnZone'].createCreep([WORK,WORK,CARRY,CARRY,CARRY,CARRY,MOVE],  creepName = Creep.getRandomName("[Harvester]"), {role: 'harvester'});
        console.log('Spawning new harvester: ' + newName);
    }

    if(upgraders.length < 3 && harvesters.length > 2) {
        var newName = Game.spawns['SpawnZone'].createCreep([WORK,CARRY,CARRY,CARRY,MOVE,MOVE], creepName = Creep.getRandomName("[Upgrader]"), {role: 'upgrader'});
        console.log('Spawning new upgrader: ' + newName);
    }

    if(builders.length < 2 && harvesters.length > 2) {
        var newName = Game.spawns['SpawnZone'].createCreep([WORK,CARRY,CARRY,MOVE,MOVE], creepName = Creep.getRandomName("[Builder]"), {role: 'builder'});
        console.log('Spawning new builder: ' + newName);
    }

    if(voyagers.length < 0 && harvesters.length > 2) {
        var newName = Game.spawns['SpawnZone'].createCreep([MOVE], creepName = Creep.getRandomName("[Voyager]"), {role: 'voyager'});
        console.log('Spawning new voyager: ' + newName);
    }

    if(attackers.length < 0 && harvesters.length > 2) {
        var newName = Game.spawns['SpawnZone'].createCreep([ATTACK,ATTACK,MOVE], creepName = Creep.getRandomName("[Attacker]"), {role: 'attacker'});
        console.log('Spawning new Attacker: ' + newName);
    }

    if(transporters.length < 0 && harvesters.length > 2) {
        var newName = Game.spawns['SpawnZone'].createCreep([WORK,CARRY,MOVE], creepName = Creep.getRandomName("[Transporter]"), {role: 'transporter'});
        console.log('Spawning new Transporter: ' + newName);
    }

    if(healers.length < 0 && harvesters.length > 2) {
        var newName = Game.spawns['SpawnZone'].createCreep([HEAL,MOVE,MOVE], creepName = Creep.getRandomName("[Healer]"), {role: 'healer'});
        console.log('Spawning new Healer: ' + newName);
    }

    if(repairers.length < 0 && harvesters.length > 2) {
        var newName = Game.spawns['SpawnZone'].createCreep([CARRY,CARRY,WORK,MOVE,MOVE], creepName = Creep.getRandomName("[Repairer]"), {role: 'repairer'});
        console.log('Spawning new Repairer: ' + newName);
    }




    for(var name in Game.creeps) {
        var creep = Game.creeps[name];
        if(creep.memory.role == 'harvester') { roleHarvester.run(creep); }
        if(creep.memory.role == 'upgrader') { roleUpgrader.run(creep); }
        if(creep.memory.role == 'builder') { roleBuilder.run(creep); }
        if(creep.memory.role == 'voyager') { roleVoyager.run(creep); }
        if(creep.memory.role == 'attacker') { roleAttacker.run(creep); }
        if(creep.memory.role == 'transporter') { roleTransporter.run(creep); }
        if(creep.memory.role == 'healer') { roleHealer.run(creep); }
        if(creep.memory.role == 'repairer') { roleRepairer.run(creep); }
    }
}
```

Now from my role.builder file i try to write an IF-Else statement that has to check a variable from the main:

```
if (main.harvesters.length > 2){...}
```

But i get the error 'main os not defined'
How do i call te main file otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is highly inefficient: You iterate over the `Game.creeps` collection multiple times (I counted 8 times at least). If you wish to count creeps in roles I suggest you use

```
var groups = _.groupBy(Game.creeps, (c) => { return c.memory.role; });
```

This will return an object with each role as a key with behind the key a collection of all creeps in that specific role:

```
{
    harvester: [Creep, Creep, Creep],
    builder: [Creep],
    upgrader: [Creep, Creep, Creep]
}
```

I suppose you would want to have this information on a per room basis instead of globally, since a low level room should behave differently than a high level room(in the sense that higher level rooms probably have less creeps).

No idea about the lifetime of Game objects, but if you loop over `Game.rooms` in the beginning of your creep update routine, like below, you would have this information immediately available when needed and only need to loop through it once:

```
for (var name in Game.rooms) {
    var room = Game.rooms[name];
    room.roles = _.groupBy(room.find(FIND_MY_CREEPS), (c) => { return c.memory.role; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it out myself just now.
If i make something liek this:

```
var count = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'harvester');
```

I can make an if-else easily with the 'count.length' var :)